# Calendar events are missing on sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to view the calendar events using the day view scope by feeding the url with the right query strings but with no luck so far.

Basically I tried all these cases with no luck :(

SPSite/webpartpage.aspx?CalendarPeriod=Day&CalendarDate=11/1/2011

SPSite/webpartpage.aspx?CalendarPeriod=day&CalendarDate=11/1/2011

SPSite/webpartpage.aspx?CalendarPeriod=Day&CalendarDate=11%2F1%2F2011

SPSite/webpartpage.aspx?CalendarPeriod=day&CalendarDate=11%2F1%2F2011

any idea why no events what so ever appear on that day.

thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out; it was more like trial and error.

I just replaced all slashes in date into spaces like this

`SPSite/webpartpage.aspx?CalendarPeriod=day&CalendarDate=11 1 2011`

It worked like a charm :)